# setInterval not working in Opera

Tags: javascript, opera

I am trying to make an element blink (by toggeling visibility of the element) but its not working in Opera for whatever reason. Works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Here's a fiddle with a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/UDWkK/2/

I don't think I have made any obvious errors.

Tested in Opera 12

Code:

```
var blinker;
function blink(elem) {
    clearInterval(blinker);
    blinker = setInterval(function() {
        if ($(elem).css('visibility') === 'hidden'){
            $(elem).css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else {
            $(elem).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: It is working (opera 12.15, Win7;JQuery 2.0.2), outside jsfiddle.

Comment: This is error thrown in scripts section of opera dragonfly: http://i.imgur.com/Mokr8Fd.png?1 (in jquery, just in jsfiddle). However, code is working fine, outside jsfiddle (tested offline, too): http://jsbin.com/awexox/1 ... Odd, something related to frames, some guru will have explanation, i hope. :) P.S. http://fiddle.jshell.net/UDWkK/show/ - frames are problem, def. :)

Comment: @nevermind: you don't happen to know why it does not work in Internet Explorer? The very same code.

Comment: It is working, at least in IE 10, again, outside jsfiddle iframes... i am curious too. :)

Answer (score 2):

As @nevermind noted in the comments above the problem is not with Opera. The problem is with the jsFiddle iframes. Note that jsFiddle is still in alpha stage. Hence there are bound to be some quirks. Hopefully the developers will fix it soon.

Nevertheless the code you provided doesn't really need jQuery, and `setInterval` works perfectly fine in Opera 12. For example this is what I did, and it blinks away nicely: http://jsfiddle.net/XwEhj/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in a corner buggy case.

When it's comes to user interface, it's not a good practice to rely on the state of the graphic objects to find out the state of the view. In other terms, you don't want to "read" the state of the view in the HTML elements, but rather in a variable or a set of variables called a view model.

I suggest that you rewrite your code this way, and I think there's a good chance to work around the bug:

```
var blinker;
function blink(elem) {
    clearInterval(blinker);

    var visible = false;
    blinker = setInterval(function() {
        visible = !visible;
        $(elem).css('visibility', visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    }, 500);
}
```